# Hibernate 6 - cannot create temporary table error when executing "coalesce" function

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, db2, hibernate-6.x

I am in the process of migrating an inherited application from springboot 2.7 and hibernate 5 to springboot 3 and hibernate 6 but I am encountering some problems with hibernate. Currently I am getting the following error when running `query.getResultList()`:

> ... [A temporary table could not be created because there is no available system temporary table space that has a compatible page size.. SQLCODE=-1585, SQLSTATE=54048, DRIVER=4.19.77]

I narrowed down the issue to statement that it's being used for sorting:

```
        final SortPropertiesResolver sortResolver = new SortPropertiesResolver.Builder()
            .addMapping("displayTitle", "LOWER(COALESCE(dna.value, p.name))")
            .build();
```

The final query looks something like this:

`FROM Profile$Active p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.displayNameAttribute dna WHERE p.client.id = :clientId order by LOWER(COALESCE(dna.value, p.name)) asc`

If I remove the `coalesce` function it runs through but with it, it simply fails with error already. I was checking the documentation and the migration guide and the only thing that is mentioned about temporary tables is the strategy for bulk operations and I couldn't get it to work using any of the strategies. Some wouldn't even allow the application to run because their constructor was not compatible with my configuration which only passes the dialect to the constructor.

Worth mentioning that this query is aimed at a db2 instance.

I am not an hibernate expert or close to it and I hope that I am missing something obvious to some people here. If someone could point me out in the right direction I would be very thankful.

Comment: I added the db2 tag.  Look at (or have your DBA look at) your db2 instance configuration to ensure the appropriate system temporary tablespace is configured and available to your application.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I have no access to the db configuration but what makes me suspicious is that with springboot 2.7 hibernate 5 it was working fine. Is this temporary table space requirement something new?

Comment: it does not matter that you lack access to the database configuration. What matters is that you speak with your DBA, as this is an elementary thing to resolve, because without help from that person you will be forced to make code changes in avoidance tactics.

Comment: I understand, I already reach out to my DBA and I am waiting feedback, but my question still remains, what change came with hibernate 6 that it now requires this temporary space when it did not before? Also, code wise, what "avoidance tactics" could be done? Not that I want to do them, just want to be aware and prepared. Thank you

Comment: Study the docs for SQL1585N to educate yourself about spills for sorts and joins and other operations. Wise DBAs always ensure that system temp tablespaces for all 4 pagesizes exist (along with matching bufferpools), and same for user-temporary tablespaces. Avoiding tactics might involve changing predicates, adding indexes, removing redundant columns from result-sets, changing join conditions ,  verifying suitable runstats, optimizer hints, housekeeping and many more. All covered by docs.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll try to put it to good use.

Comment: @mao I am in the process of following your advice and reading all these docs but quick question: is there a way for me to understand what's the space requirements of certain hibernate operation? Thank again

Comment: You can capture the SQL emitted by your orm, and you can ask Db2 to show you the access-plan for the statement(s), and  detailed access plans show which operators in the plan spill (see db2exfmt) and estimated cardinalities. Space requirements vary according to volumetrics , runtime ram considerations and query detail.

Comment: @mao I suggest that you write an answer based on your two comments. The question has value for future readers, and your suggestions summarize nicely how to address the problem.  There isn't really a "better" answer for this question. I'll certainly upvote :-)